# Calculator in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, calculator

this is my first C++ program. I can't seem to be able to verify the contents of the op variable in my ValidateInput function, could someone explain what I am doing wrong and give me pointers to writing good clean code!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Addition(int number1, int number2)
{
    int add = number1 + number2;
    return add;
}

int Subtraction(int number1, int number2)
{
    int subtract = number1 - number2;
    return subtract;
}

int Multiplication(int number1, int number2)
{
    int multiply = number1 * number2;
    return multiply;
}

int Modulo(int number1, int number2)
{
    int mod = number1 % number2;
    return mod;
}

int Division(int number1, int number2)
{
    int divide = number1 / number2;
    return divide;
}

int ValidateInput(int number1, string op, int number2)
{
    if (cin.fail()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (cin.good()) {
        return true;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int number1, number2;
    string op;

    cout << "C++ Calculator\n\n";
    cout << "Enter number 1: ", cin >> number1;
    cout << "Enter operator(+, /, %, *, -): ", cin >> op;
    cout << "Enter number 2: ", cin >> number2;

    if (ValidateInput(number1, op, number2) == false) {
        cout << "FALSE";
    }

    else if (ValidateInput(number1, op, number2) == true) {
        //Input seems ok
        if (op == "+") {
            cout << Addition(number1, number2);
        }
        else if (op == "-") {
            cout << Subtraction(number1, number2);
        }
        else if (op == "/") {
            cout << Division(number1, number2);
        }
        else if (op == "*") {
            cout << Multiplication(number1, number2);
        }
        else if (op == "%") {
            cout << Modulo(number1, number2);
        }
        else {
            cout << "Invalid operator"; //ValidateInput function doesn't seem to notice if operator input is valid or not
        }
    }
}
```

And when it detects that the invalid isn't valid it still goes through the whole program before ending. [image: error_msg]

Comment: You haven't written any code to validate op in the above example. If you have tried some code which didn't work, can you post that?

Comment: Far as I know ValidateInput cin checks all the arguments

Comment: Can someone clarify the syntax: `cout << foo, cin >> bar;`? What is the comma?

Comment: If you want a code review, you should ask on [codereview.se] (but only once you have working code). But `if (expression == false) {...} else if (expression == true) {...}` can be replaced by `if (!expression) {...} else {...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea to validate the stream state after you have read from it again already.

A good idiom to use is:

```
int i;
if(!(std::cin >> i)) {
  std::cout << "Error reading input" << std::endl;
}
```

This will check if reading and formatting the input as a number succeeded. Checking `fail` will not do this.

Your validate function examine the actual contents of the variables not where they originated (possible overflows given a certain operation, is the `op` string in the expected range, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Aren't `Division` should return `float` or `double` instead of  `int` for correct result?

Comment: You'd still get integer division if you don't cast at least one of the operands.

Comment: True. I was thinking about flaws of division of `int`  but my thoughts went wrong way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Change this code

```
cout << "Enter number 1: ", cin >> number1;           // ',' is not valid use ';'
cout << "Enter operator(+, /, %, *, -): ", cin >> op;
cout << "Enter number 2: ", cin >> number2;
```

to

```
cout << "Enter number 1: ";
cin >> number1;
cout << "Enter operator(+, /, %, *, -): "; 
cin >> op;
cout << "Enter number 2: "; 
cin >> number2;
```

Comment: I don't think its valid syntax but if it is working for you then its good.